# How do I centre an <a> element inside of a <div> element whilst limiting the clickable area of the <a> element?

Tags: html, css

I have a *div* element at the top of my webpage which contains a link (using an *a* tag). The *div* element spans the full width of the page, and I've managed to centre the *a* element in it horizontally.
The issue is that the user can click anywhere inside the *div* to open the link, whereas I want to limit this "clickable area" to just the text in the *a* element.

```css
#header_div {} #link_home {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0.05em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_div">
  <a id="link_home" href="index.html">HOME</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that I embedded your code into a runnable example but in the process I removed the white color from your text so as to make it readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links are inline by default. It means you can use the `text-align` property on the parent, and have the text horizontally align to the `left`, the `right` or `center`:

```css
#header_div {
  /* note that all the font-* rules are inherited to children */
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}
#link_home {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_div">
  <a id="link_home" href="index.html">HOME</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd move the `text-align: center;` from the link up to the div and set the link's display to inline-block or remove it so it defaults to inline.

```css
 #link_home {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 0.05em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header_div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_div">
  <a id="link_home" href="index.html">HOME</a>
</div>
```